# Accessing AppResources in a separate project without build dependency

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

I have two projects in the same solution, A the application project and B, the library project. A project depends on project B. I am trying to find a way to access AppResources located in project A from project B. On Android, I could just pass the app context from A to project B and access the resources :

```
public static String getStringResourceByName(final String pStringResourceName, final Context pContext) {
    int resId = pContext.getResources().getIdentifier(pStringResourceName, "string", pContext.getPackageName());
    if (resId == 0) {
        return null;
    } else {
        return pContext.getString(resId);
    }
}
```

Is there a way to do something similar on Windows Phone? Are there any other approaches that could be used while keeping project B independent from project A?

Comment: Have you trying making a function that you can pass Project A's Application.Current.Resources to.  It's just a ResourceDictionary.

Comment: I forgot to mention that I am trying to access the localized strings from AppResources. Thank you for trying to help, but unfortunately it contains LocalizedStrings object, which is located in project A, and project B has no knowledge of it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have managed to find a way to get to those resources by passing AppResources.ResourceManager to project B, and afterwards getting values from it like this :

```
return resourceManager.GetString(stringResourceName, System.Globalization.CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
```